# Intellij Completion Contributor Completion Resultset

Tags: java, intellij-idea, autocomplete, autosuggest, intellij-plugin

Is there any method to add element to the top of suggestion list.

`resultSet.addElement(LookupElementBuilder.create(element.getNodeName()));`

Added given suggestions to the end of suggestion list. I want to add my suggestions to the top or does not matter if other suggestions at the given point is removed. 
please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completion sorting criteria are very complex, so without a context it's hard to give a comprehensive answer. But most likely the following will help:

`resultSet.addElement(PrioritizedLookupElement.withPriority(aBigNumber, lookupElement));`

Comment: it works peter. thank you again. 
this is how i apply it for any others use
                                double i=2500;// a big value to improve priority
                                while (iterator.hasNext()) {                 resultSet.addElement(PrioritizedLookupElement.withPriority(LookupElementBuilder.create((String) iterator.next()),i));                                    iterator.next()));                                    
                                    i++;
                                }